# CSP Formulation of an algebraic problem

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Question]

Is anyone able to explain how to do this? I'm not looking for the complete answer, I would settle for a "how to for dummies" explanation of how this is supposed to be solved.

I understand constraints, but in the first example it would seem to me that the second half of the first partial assignment $x_2=-1$ is a violation of the constraint 2, that says $x_1 > x_2$... when down below it says both $x_1$, and $x_2$, are $-1$